# Como puedo obtener datos de un servicio en angular sin recargar la pagina

Tags: angular, api, angular8

tengo un chat, la pregunta es como puedo obtener los comentarios que van agregando sin recargar la pagina

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
GetComentarios(body:any){
    return this.http.post(this.url + 'GetComments',body);
  }
```

ese es el servicio que me obtiene los comentarios

Comment: Sockets mi estimado...

Answer (score 3):

AJAX es la forma en la que puedes pedir datos del servidor sin recargar la página, por lo que veo haces un POST, esto funciona al cargar la página, esto esta bien, sin embargo, para hacer cambios en tiempo real debes usar WebSockets, este es un protocolo para hacer cambios en tiempo real, ya que si lo intentas con AJAX lo más seguro es que el servidor se sobrecargue y por ende se caiga, para hacer una conexión a WebSockets puedes hacerlo así

```javascript
new WebSocket("ws://servidor")
```

[Puedes leer más en la MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/WebSocket)

[Conectar a WebSockets con angular](https://medium.com/briebug-blog/making-use-of-websockets-in-angular-way-easier-than-you-expected-25dd0061db1d)

Comment: pregunta, debo de configurar la api del backend para que acepte peticiones webSocket?

Comment: Por lo general los WebSockets crean un puerto, puedes buscar algunos ejemplos en internet, si tienes tu API ya hecha puedes aplicarle configuraciones según en el lenguaje en el que está tu API

Comment: la api esta en netcore c#

Comment: Puedes ir viendo algunos ejemplos en internet, si te llama la atención alguno lo puedes descargar, te tengo que decir que no hay que poner el archivo que majea WebSockets en un document root o en los archivos del sitios, tienes que ejecutarlos por consola

Answer (score 0):

precisamente realice un proyecto sobre esto mismo hace poco, con angular 8 y api en netcore C#, puedes realizar la obtención de datos en tiempo real utilizando SignalR para C#.